# sort descending linkedhashmap by value

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, hashmap, linkedhashmap

i have 3 hashmap :

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> tokenUnikTF= new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> tokenUnikDF= new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<String, HashMap<String, Double>> tokenUnikWeight= new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

the difference between the 3 hashmap above only in value, their key is the same.

here's how i add tokenUnikWeight's key and value :

```
for (String key5 : tokenUnikTF.keySet()) {
    tokenUnikWeight.put(key5, calculateWeight());
 }
```

i want to print them all together, but in **descending order by tokenUnikWeight's value**

here's my sorting code :

```
public static LinkedHashMap<String,Double> sortHashMap() {
    List<Map.Entry<String, Double>> list = new LinkedList<>(tokenUnikWeight.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Double>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Double> o1, Map.Entry<String, Double> o2) {
            return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    });

    Map<String, Double> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : list) {
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return (LinkedHashMap<String, Double>) result;

}
```

and here is my print code :

```
tokenUnikWeight = sortHashMap();

for (String key5 : tokenUnikWeight.keySet()) {
   System.out.printf("%s - %d - %d - %f\n", key5, tokenUnikTF.get(key5), tokenUnikDF.get(key5), tokenUnikWeight.get(key5));
 }
```

the output is i got null in some tf and df also my weight is sorted in ascending not descending :
[image: i got null output]

someone help me please, i do lot of googling but still the same, it return null in some tf and df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your comparator to : `return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());` for descending order. As for null values, are you sure that those keys are present and their values are not null in tokenUnikTF, DF?

Comment: You said : the difference between the 3 hashmap above only in value, their key is the same.  As for null values, are you sure that those keys are present and their values are not null in tokenUnikTF, DF?

Comment: actually tokenUnikWeight's key is based on tokenUnikTF : here's the code :

 for (String key5 : tokenUnikTF.keySet()) {
                        tokenUnikWeight.put(key5, calculateWeight());
}

Comment: key might be there, but if there is no value, it will print null.

Comment: i made it. haha thankyou. you're right, there's null value in TF ;) tysm

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `(o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue())` with `(o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue())` in your `Comparator` implementation.

Comment: thankyou for helping me with the descending order ^^